# iOS - How to trigger music play events(Next, Previous, Play, Pause) of any music player?

Tags: ios

I need to create an application to control the music play in iOS device remotely. Is it possible to control the music play events of another application from our application?
Please help me with the possibilities of achieving this.

Thanks

Comment: This can be done using one socket based server communication. The app will be in sync with server to receive commands and provide current stats.

Comment: another application on same device ?

Comment: What do you mean by “remotely”?

Comment: @GaryMakin, Lion, I need to control the music play from another device. For that, I will be creating a Host and Client app. The host will be playing the music and when Client triggers the event it should notify the Host and Host have to trigger the music event accordingly. For notifying the Host I am going to use the Firebase RBD.

Comment: @DevanshuSaini I am planning to use Firebase for update the app. What I need to know is the possibilities of controlling the music play events of an existing music player such as Gaana, Saavn, iTunes, etc. from my application.

Comment: I don't understand why you need to know the possibilities of other apps, do you want to build an universal app remote?
Using network if bluetooth connection is available is bad practice btw

Comment: @omujeebr first you need to have one socket based server for persistent connection say chat servers. Best example is nodeJS based web socket servers. Your app will listen to socket events, say pause one song or play some random music for a disabled person. Please go through case study of chat server and app consuming its api for more info.

Comment: @DevanshuSaini Thanks for your comment. I was thinking to use the Firebase real-time database as that provides the same experience as the socket connection.  But unfortunately, iOS does not allow listening value changes in background. So for my requirement, I have to use APNS for notify the host machine. Luckily firebase allows upstream push notifications.